# Magento how do I set a cloned product to not be in any categories?

Tags: magento

I can create copies of a product using the 'duplicate' method and it seems to work nicely. However, I would like to unassign the duplicated product from being in any categories, yet `$clone->setCategoryIds()` is not doing it for me. Is there a neat way to do this?

I also have images already in place with the duplicated product however they are not selected for the main image, thumbnail and small image. Is there any easy way to do this too?

```
            $clone=$product->duplicate();
            $clone->setSku($clonedSku);
            $clone->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
            $clone->setPrice(5);
            $clone->setCategoryIds();
            $clone->setStatus(1);
            $clone->getResource()->save($clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
$clone->unlockAttribute('category_ids');
```

before

```
$this->unlockAttribute('category_ids');.
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it did not actually work with my code, however, I was not aware of the 'unlockAttribute' method so I have even more Magento learning to do!